# Home Network, How to install SSL XAMPP Self-Hosted Website

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ssl, xampp

I use laptop IP Lan 192.168.88.248.
I opened port 80 on this IP. Hairpin NAT in LAN.
I registered the domain abc.mooo.com at freedns.afraid.org and assigned it to my WAN IP.
I install default XAMPP (C:\xampp\htdocs) 
I installed WordPress on it.
Edit file C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-config.php

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://abc.mooo.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://abc.mooo.com' );
```

It work when i access http://abc.mooo.com from outside (Internet Cafe, my company)
But Chrome slows it down to 5–6 seconds because it doesn't have SSL.

I registered zerossl.com. And got 3 files: ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt, and private.key
I extracted it to

```
C:\xampp\apache\crt\abc.mooo.com\ca_bundle.crt
C:\xampp\apache\crt\abc.mooo.com\certificate.crt
C:\xampp\apache\crt\abc.mooo.com\private.key
```

I edited C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf.
Add this to the bottom line.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/
    ServerName abc.mooo.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "crt/abc.mooo.com/certificate.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/abc.mooo.com/private.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I edited file C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-config.php

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://abc.mooo.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://abc.mooo.com' );
```

### Restart Apache

It not work.
Should I open port 443 on my Mikrotik router?
Did my sequence thing go correctly?

I want to self-host a website on my laptop with SSL so people don't have to type http://abc.mooo.com. Just type abc.mooo.com it works with SSL.

Comment: Someone, please help me.